# Adding a birthdate using php to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

I modified the form and the php script, but I am not still have results. Right now when I fill the form then press the button, I just get a white screen in the Apache Web Server, here is the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insertform3.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
            Birhtday: <input type="date" name="birthday"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and This is the PHP Form:

```
<?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root'); 
define('PASS', 'password');
define('DBNAME', 'database');

$db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " .    $db->connect_error;
}


if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

     if (!empty($name) && !empty($phonenumber) && !empty($birthday)) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO form_data (name,phonenumber,birthday) 
            VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $conn  = $db->prepare($query);

        if ($conn->execute(array(
             $name,
             $phonenumber,
             $birthday
        ))) {
            header('location: http://localhost/insertform-2.html');
        } else {
        echo 'error';
        }
        $db->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting when you submit the form, if any?

Comment: It's always best to use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` instead of `if($_POST['submit']){` and try using `if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phonenumber'])) {` instead of `if (!empty($name) && !empty($phonenumber)) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', 'xxxxxxxxx');
define('DBNAME', 'database');

$db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}


if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $birthday    = $_POST['birthday'];

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($phonenumber)) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO formdatabase (name,phonenumber,bithday) 
                VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $conn  = $db->prepare($query);

        if ($conn->execute(array(
            $name,
            $phonenumber,
            $birthday
        ))) {
            header('location: http://localhost/insertform-2.html');
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }
        $db->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm sure you meant `(name,phonenumber,birthday)` you wrote `bithday` missing the `r` --- You should also make notes of what you suggested the OP to do, and include what you added.

Comment: Thanks for helo samitha I will test your script thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that the birthdate is entered in the correct format yyy-mm-dd and in your database set the birthdate to type DATE.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];

if (!empty($name) && !empty($phonenumber) && !empty($birthdate)) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO formdatabase (name,phonenumber) 
        VALUES($name,$phonenumber,$birthdate)";
```

Comment: I did NOT downvote this, but the person who did, may have done so because of what you wrote `VALUES($name,$phonenumber,$birthdate)` which should have been wrapped in quotes `VALUES('$name','$phonenumber','$birthdate')` Plus you only have `(name,phonenumber)` where there's a missing `birthday` which should have been `(name,phonenumber,birthday)` IF the OP has a column named like that.

Comment: I just added what he had missing, I missed those I apologize. And thanks for helping me out earlier on my question!

Comment: Thanks to your answer yuriah, how I can add the format  of yyy-mm-dd on my sql database ?

Comment: On the birth field of your html make sure to give them 3 boxes for the year which should be 4 numbers the month which should be 2 numbers and the day which should be 2 numbers as well (ex:1996-03-01) for March 1, 1996. since your using 3 boxes u gotta give them a name and then on php u get their values $year $month $day then to enter it on the database on VALUES([other values here], '$year."-".$month."-".$day')